# "potentially dangerous request.path" error randomly showing up in my error logs, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.5

I am using the ELMAH to get emails when ever my production site gets an error and every few days I get a "System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)." on my index page. I am not sure what is causing this and how to stop it. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do? If it will help I will post my ASPX and/or C# code for the page just let me know.

Comment: Bots trying to hack your site? Nothing you can do about it except making sure your code is secure.

Comment: I second the comment above. Do you have an example of such a request from your logs (namely the URI)?

Comment: I am on Asure so I dont have the raw logs but I have the full crash screen dump if any info on that would be of help. If it is a hack attemp I am actualy happy that it is not an error in my code.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete, not being able to look at access logs would be bad.  Except... http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/best-practices/troubleshooting-web-sites/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no solution to this issue beside ignore it.